# XMLParser skips attributes while parsing XML Schema file

Tags: python, xsd, lxml

I need to read the XML Schema File and extract only these elements, which have field `minOccurs="0"`. But I face the problem, when the XML Parser skips that fields while parsing document.

It's just like I show you in code below.

I have an example XML file:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:sql="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:mapping-schema">
    <xsd:include schemaLocation="def.xml"/>
    <xsd:element name="MainElementName">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="A">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:attribute name="AA" required="False" type="string"/>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="B" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:attribute name="BA" type="string"/>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Then I parse it with this code:

```py
    with open(xsd_path, 'r'):
        try:
            parser = et.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
            tree = et.parse(xsd_path, parser)
            tmp_text = et.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True, encoding=str)
        except IOError as e:
            print(e)
```

And I get the output:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:sql="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:mapping-schema">
    <xsd:include schemaLocation="def.xml"/>
    <xsd:element name="MainElementName">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="A">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:attribute name="AA" type="string"/>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="B">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:attribute name="BA" type="string"/>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

I don't know why the parser skips the `required` field in attribute and `min/maxOccurs` in element. Does anyone knows how to solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is incorrect, I couldn't get it to compile. For instance, `ElementTree.tostring()` takes an `Element` instance, but you're passing an `ElementTree` instance (`tree`).

This code works for me:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

parser = et.XMLParser()
tree = et.parse('/path/to.xml', parser)
tmp_text = et.tostring(tree.getroot(), encoding='unicode')
print(tmp_text)
```

With Python 3.6.8 the output is:

```xml
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:include schemaLocation="def.xml" />
    <xs:element name="MainElementName">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="A">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:attribute name="AA" required="False" type="string" />
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="B">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:attribute name="BA" type="string" />
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: The OP is very likely using lxml, which accepts an `ElementTree` instance as argument to `tostring()`.

Comment: Yes, I was using lxml... and that was the mistake. Thank you very much

Comment: What exactly was a mistake? This answer does not explain why "parser skips the required field in attribute and min/maxOccurs in element".